# Excel how to insert below cell value and skip every other row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a excel spreadsheet like:

[image: Current spreadsheet]

What I would like:

[image: What I'd like the spreadsheet to be like]

Thus, what I am trying to achieve is for the current cell to take the value of the cell directly below value and repeat, skipping each of the directly below cells.

For example, cell `B2` will take the value 10.62 (i.e. cell `B3`); then cell `B3` will be skipped; then, cell `B4` will take value of 13.26 (i.e. cell `B5`), and following suite...

I have tried this formula:

```
=INDEX(B2:$B$4518,ROWS(B2:B2)*2)
```

Then, selecting that row and the row below, which doesn't have any formulae, and dragging down. But, sadly unless I only drag down one then reselect it doesn't work correctly. It seems to take the first selected cells value and then adds 1.

Comment: please post also screenshot of current- and desired outputs, your question is unclear now.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding correctly, in row 2 you want the value from row 3, in row 3 you want to keep its own value, in row 4 you want the value from row 5...etc?

If that's correct, there's a fairly straightforward process you can use - in C2, enter the formula `=$B3`. In C3, enter the same formula, `=$B3`. That should put the same value into both cells. Then highlight **both** cells and use the fill handle to copy them into the other cells. This should get you the repeating pattern you want.

Comment: I need the values in the B column though.

Comment: You would use the C column to create the values, then you can use Copy | Paste Special (Values) to place the results over the top of the existing values in B.

Answer (score 0):

because you will need the B value for 2 cells, copy the B column to the C column otherwise will eventually get a reference issue

then in the B column, replace with the following formula

- =IF(EVEN(ROW()),C3,C2)

The if checks to see if needs to go down 1 or just go across.

Row() returns the row this is on. In the case of B2 it is 2
Even() checks if something is even. For a 2 this is true.

IF (test,True_Action,False_Action) . The if works by making a test then choosing either a true or a false action. Since Even is true for b2, the true_action points to C3.

Note. This has the side effect of expanding your data range. A copy /paste special could be used over the b row to replace with the new values. Then afterwards, the C column could be deleted.

Comment: Very insightful, I went with the option below which seems to have done the trick fantastically.